# convert a json to a csv, array

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I'd like to convert below file into a csv file, I think `jq` would be the suitable tool for it.

```
[
  [
    "123456789012",
    "071395e8xxxxxxxx",
    bad,
    failed
  ],
  [
    "098765432123",
    "094e9c34d3xxxxxxxx",
    good,
    successful
  ],
  ...
]
```

to

```
123456789012,071395e8xxxxxxxx, bad, failed
098765432123,094e9c34d3xxxxxxxx,good,successful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the input as shown is not quite valid JSON, so you would have to tweak it somehow before presenting it to JSON. The jq command for converting to CSV would then be along the lines of:

```
jq -r '.[] | @csv' input.json
```

Comment: you are the super hero, mate.